# How to get COUNT and SUM of column values from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, join

TABLE 1

```
NAME               PLAN             OPEN           LOCATION        BALANCE          UNum
John               A                3/12/2023      27              999.99           11
Michelle           A                3/17/2023      13              1200.00          7
James              B                3/18/2023      9               4500.00          23
Juan               D                3/11/2023      9               234.20           37
Michelle           B                3/16/2023      13              594.00           7
```

Table 2

```
NAME               PLAN              OPEN           LOCATION        BALANCE         UNum

Michelle           H                 3/09/2023      13              1549.00         7
Michelle           J                 3/11/2023      13              749.00          7
Juan               J                 3/13/2023      9               1700.00         37
```

Table 3

```
NAME                PLAN              OPEN           LOCATION        BALANCE        UNum
Michelle            M                 3/18/2023      13              498.02         7
John                P                 3/20/2023      27              9800.00        11
```

TABLE 4

```
NAME                   LOCATION         UNum
JOHN                   27               11
Michelle               13               7
James                  9                23
Juan                   9                37
```

How do I generate this group by Location and join by UNum:

```
NAME              LOCATION      TABLE1PLANCOUNT    TABLE1PLANBALANCE   TABLE2PLANCOUNT   TABLE2PLANBALANCE   TABLE3PLANCOUNT    TABLE3PLANBALANCE
John              27             1                 999.99              0                 0                   1                  9800.00
Michelle          13             2                 1794.00             2                 2298.00             1                  498.02
James             9              1                 4500.00             0                 0                   0                  0
Juan              9              1                 234.00              1                 1700.00             0                  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would find a common denominator, here it cane be name an Location.

I choose LOCATION, but changing it ot NAME, is not difficult, if a NAMe can have multiple locatons

```
SELECT
  t4.NAME, t4.LOCATION 
   , COALESCE(TABLE1PLANCOUNT,0) TABLE1PLANCOUNT ,COALESCE(TABLE1PLANBALANCE,0) TABLE1PLANBALANCE   
   , COALESCE(TABLE2PLANCOUNT,0) TABLE2PLANCOUNT,COALESCE(TABLE2PLANBALANCE,0)  TABLE2PLANBALANCE  
   , COALESCE(TABLE3PLANCOUNT,0) TABLE3PLANCOUNT,COALESCE(TABLE3PLANBALANCE,0) TABLE3PLANBALANCE
FROM 
Table4 t4 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT LOCATION , COUNT(*) TABLE1PLANCOUNT , SUM(BALANCE) TABLE1PLANBALANCE    FROM Table1 GROUP BY LOCATION) t1 ON t4.LOCATION = t1.LOCATION 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT LOCATION , COUNT(*) TABLE2PLANCOUNT, SUM(BALANCE) TABLE2PLANBALANCE  FROM Table2 GROUP BY LOCATION) t2 ON t4.LOCATION = t2.LOCATION 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT LOCATION , COUNT(*) TABLE3PLANCOUNT    , SUM(BALANCE) TABLE3PLANBALANCE FROM Table3 GROUP BY LOCATION ) t3 ON t4.LOCATION = t3.LOCATION
```

Comment: I should do group by Location I believe